# How can i insert an handler for an HTML object?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

question is simple!

I have an object like this:

```
new Ext.Panel({

        id: 'Panel',
        fullscreen: true,
        dockedItems: [
                  dock:...,
                  width: ...,
                  listeners: { el: /*TOUCHEVENTS*/ },
                  html: '<object id='objectID' data="blabla"/>'
        ]

    });
```

How can i add an event (like tap or pinch) on the HTML object with id= ObjectID ???

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var p = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'Panel',
    fullscreen: true,
    dockedItems: [
        html: '<object id='objectID' data="blabla"/>'
    ]
});
p.on('render', function() {
    Ext.get("objectID").on('click', function() {
        alert('imclicket');
    });    
});
```

Comment: Now work, but console says:
"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml"
And click event doesn't appear :(

Comment: Then it`s some another problem. Try to scope it without any Ext.Panel and just with pure HTML and with only `Ext.get("objectID").on('click'` part.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use event delegation to makes possibile what you request.
Event delegation allow you to set tap listeners on a specific target on your panel inner HTML object. I write you an example that show you how to do that:

```
Ext.setup({
onReady: function() {

    //Definition of a handler function
    var myHandler = function(){
        Ext.Msg.alert('What???','Did you Tap me?');
    };

    //Definition of a simple Panel
    var p = new Ext.Panel({
        fullscreen: true,
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            dock: 'top',
            height: '30',
            html: '<div id="myObject">Tap me please</div>',
            listeners: {
                body: {
                    tap: myHandler,
                    delegate: '#myObject'     
                 }
            }
        }]
    });

}
});
```

If you run this code, you will see that, when you tap on the "Tap me Please!" div, your event will be fired.

Hope this helps.